# Select column(s) corresponding to max/min of another column without joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, case

I have a `table` (`id`, `employee_id`, `device_id`, `logged_time`) ***[simplified]*** that logs attendances of employees from biometric devices.
I generate reports showing the first in and last out time of each employee by date.

Currently, I am able to fetch the first in and last out time of each employee by date, but I also need to fetch the first in and last out `device_id`s of each employee. The entries are not in sequential order of the logged time.

I do not want to (and probably cannot) use joins as in one of the reports the columns are dynamically generated and can lead to thousands of joins. Furthermore, these are subqueries and are joined to other queries to get further details.

A sample setup of the table and queries are at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bc755/4

The first one just shows lists the entry and exit time by date of every employee

```
select
    attendance_logs.employee_id,
    DATE(attendance_logs.logged_time) as date,
    TIME(MIN(attendance_logs.logged_time)) as entry_time,
    TIME(MAX(attendance_logs.logged_time)) as exit_time
from attendance_logs
group by date, attendance_logs.employee_id
```

The second one builds up an attendance chart given a date range

```
select 
    `attendance_logs`.`employee_id`, 

    DATE(MIN(case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-18' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END)) as date_2017_09_18, 
    MIN(case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-18' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END) as entry_2017_09_18, 
    MAX(case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-18' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END) as exit_2017_09_18, 

    DATE(MIN(case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-19' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END)) as date_2017_09_19, 
    MIN(case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-19' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END) as entry_2017_09_19,
    MAX(case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-19' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END) as exit_2017_09_19

    /*
     * dynamically generated columns for dates in date range
     */
from `attendance_logs` 
where `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` >= '2017-09-18 00:00:00' and `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` <= '2017-09-19 23:59:59' 
group by `attendance_logs`.`employee_id`;
```

**Tried:**

Similar to max and min `logged_time` of each date using `case`, tried to select the `device_id` where `logged_time` is max/min.

````
```MIN(case 
    when 
    `attendance_logs.logged_time` = MIN(
        case when DATE(`attendance_logs`.`logged_time`) 
        = '2017-09-18' THEN `attendance_logs`.`logged_time` END
    ) 
then `attendance_logs`.`device_id` end) as entry_device_2017_09_18 ```
````

This results in `invalid use of group by`

Comment: Any reason for the date-specific dynamic columns? Looks very "unrelational"...

Comment: @RomanSusi, basically, the result of the query is the "generated report" (with some changes) and this is also used in multiple places with similar but different functions. 

Fetching the daily attendance data for every employee for an entire month or months and processing this chart (with additional calculations regarding shifts, schedules etc) on the application side could potentially get complicated and run into issues with time and memory as the data is huge. Doing this on the database seems to scale well.

Suggestions on a better way will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack for your query to pick the device id for in and out by using `GROUP_CONCAT` with in `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(case when DATE(`l`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-18' THEN `l`.`device_id` END ORDER BY `l`.`device_id` desc),',',1) exit_device_2017_09_18,
```

Or if device id will be same for each in and its out then simply it can be written with `GROUP_CONCAT` only

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT case when DATE(`l`.`logged_time`) = '2017-09-18' THEN `l`.`device_id` END)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bc755/9)

Comment: won't the ordering be by the `logged_time` and not `device_id`? And no the `device_id` will be different for entry and exit.

I am interested how well this will scale? There can be potentially 100s of columns and thousands of rows.

Comment: No it will be device_id for ordering , logged_time cannot be because you are already using this as a condition. According to the provided data set there was same ids that is why i posted both solutions, For scaling the way you have already written it cannot be scaled for bigger data, that is why i called it as a *quick hack*

Comment: The sample dataset is sorta abridged and may not fully reflect actual data. So how is ordering by `device_id` getting the entry and exit devices? 

Can `coalesce` be used to get the first non-null `device_id` instead of `substring` and `group_concat`.

Also, have any suggestions on how to better these queries?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid joins I suggest you try "correlated subqueries" instead:

```
select
    employee_id
  , logdate
  , TIME(entry_time)                       entry_time
  , (select MIN(l.device_id)
     from attendance_logs l
     where l.employee_id = d.employee_id
     and l.logged_time = d.entry_time)     entry_device
  , TIME(exit_time)                        exit_time
  , (select MAX(l.device_id)
     from attendance_logs l
     where l.employee_id = d.employee_id
     and l.logged_time = d.exit_time)      exit_device
from (
      select
          attendance_logs.employee_id
        , DATE(attendance_logs.logged_time) as logdate
        , MIN(attendance_logs.logged_time) as entry_time
        , MAX(attendance_logs.logged_time) as exit_time
      from attendance_logs
      group by
          attendance_logs.employee_id
        , DATE(attendance_logs.logged_time)
      ) d
;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06e0e2/3

Note: I have used MIN() and MAX() on those subqueries only to avoid any possibility that these return more than one value. You could use **limit 1** instead if you prefer.

Note also: I do not normally recommend correlated subqueries as they can cause performance issues, but they do supply the data you need.

oh, and please try to avoid using `date` as a column name, it isn't good practice.

Comment: Won't correlated sub-queries be a performance problem if the outer query result set is very large?
I avoided correlated sub-queries as the result set will be large. the actual table may have 2Million or more records and growing. The queries are paginated though, fetching 500 at a time.

Comment: Yee (As I already stated). You have ruled out joins, so the available options are reduced. So far as I see it you are stuck with these correlated queries.